# Why does the [ head | tail ] syntax when used as an arg match a single element array in Elixir?

Tags: elixir

I noticed in iex that running `[1] = [ head | tail ]` results in a compile error. However, if you define a function, like:

```
def simple_func([ head | tail ]) do
  IO.inspect(head)
  IO.inspect(tail)
end
```

the argument seems to match. I'm assuming something is going on under the hood and I'd be curious to know what it is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The pattern to match comes on the left hand side of the `=`, not the right:

```
iex(1)> [head | tail] = [1]
[1]
iex(2)> head
1
iex(3)> tail
[]
```

Comment: realized right after posting that I was doing it wrong. thanks for clarifying

Answer (score 1):

Tail is the remainder list. In a list of one argument, it is just an empty list, so it matches, actually.

Answer (score 0):

**There are three cases** 
1. head and tail not defined before:

```
iex(1)> [1] = [head | tail] 
** (CompileError) iex:5: undefined function head/0
    (stdlib) lists.erl:1353: :lists.mapfoldl/3
    (stdlib) lists.erl:1354: :lists.mapfoldl/3
```

2. head and tail are defined with matched values

   `iex(1)> head = 1
   1
   iex(2)> tail = []
   []
   iex(3)> [1] = [head|tail]`

   In this case, the combination of head and tail (`[head|tail]`) is equal to `[1]` so matched and no error
3. head and tail are defined with not matched values

`

```
iex(1)> head = 2
2
iex(2)> tail = []
[]
iex(3)> [1] = [head|tail]
** (MatchError) no match of right hand side value: [2]
```

In this case, the combination of head and tail (`[head|tail]`) is equal to `[2]` so match error